# You've used me, haven't you?

Tags: riddle, english

A simple, one sentence riddle which I'm confident will **** your brain sideways.

*I have another part and may be started many different ways, though three of which can be completed by changing letters.*

What is it?

Hint:

> The title is an example.

Comment: @Tommy Woldt- Is the hint really a hint? Doesnt help I guess :-/

Comment: @Techidiot Well I'm not going to flat out tell what it is.

Comment: I think "contraction" (as in, *you've* and *haven't*) could fit - they have another part (the part that is left out) and have many different beginnings, but I don't know how the five completed by reducing straight lines would fit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a possibility. Is it,

> A question?

Reasoning:

> A question can be started as such: who, what, when, where, why, *how, etc. The other "part" may be the answer. Who can be converted to Why by changing one letter, and Who is an anagram of How. Who, Why, and How may be the ways of starting that can be achieved by "Changing letters".

[Intended reasoning]:

> "Completing" the start of a question is it's pairing with the corresponding answer. We have the substitution w --> t for three: What? That. Where? There. When? Then.

Comment: Great answer, though the reasoning i had in mind was changing the "W" in What, When, and Where into a "T". Completing it ("answer" being the other half) with That, Then, and There

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment on ThatAmateurRiddler's answer and remembered that I completeley forgot to accept your answer as well.

Comment: FYI you can only accept one answer,

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Speech?!

Then:

> I have another part (of speech)-an interjection. Five parts can be completed by reducing straight lines into line segments or points: Pronoun-I, Verb-WILL, Noun-TILL, Article-AN, Conjuction-IF.

Comment: Great answer, though I'm afraid I made my question a bit too broad. Ive modified it and Im sorry to say your answer isn't exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think of a:

> Question

Because:

*I have another part*

> The answer

*may be started many different ways*

> What, when, why, where, how, can...

*though three of which can be completed by changing letters*

> What, When, and Where can be completed (answered) by changing the W into a T, creating That, Then, and There

Comment: Why was this accepted when OP already stated the reasoning I had left out?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Mabye you should use @.tommywoldt to ask him directly. Also mabye it's because of how accurate the explaination is.